# How to remove hover effect from kendo grid row that is using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, kendo-grid, tr

I asked a question the other day about removing hover affect on a selected row and got the correct answer, now I am running into an issue because I am using kendo bootstrap css and now removing the hover effect on a selected row is now not working and I have tried a couple different ways to change the hover effect to stay the same color as the k-state-selected and none is working..

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      field: "age"
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [{
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 30
    },
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      age: 33
    }
  ],
  selectable: "row"
});
```

```css
.k-grid .k-state-selected {
  background: #ec971f;
}

.k-grid .k-state-selected:hover {
  background: #ec971f!important;
  color: #000;
}

.k-grid .table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
.table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background: #ec971f !important;
}

.k-grid .table-hover tbody .k-state-selected:hover {
  background: #ec971f !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: though not a good approach but if you're table won't have any pointer-events. You can simply do <div id="grid" style="pointer-events: none"></div>. This would remove the impact on hover. However, you can see my answer if you want to alter the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      field: "age"
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [{
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 30
    },
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      age: 33
    },
    {
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 30
    },
    {
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 30
    },
  ],
  selectable: "row"
});
```

```css
.k-grid tr:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.k-grid tr.k-alt:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```